# Is the Below function Surjective

Tags: functions

Consider a below function

$f(x)=x^5+1$

defined over $R \rightarrow R$

I know it is one-to-one, because $(f(x_1)=f(x_2)) \rightarrow x_1=x_2$

If I compute its inverse

$y=x^5+1$

$y-1=x^5$

$x=(y-1)^{\frac{1}{5}}$

This implies inverse for all Reals $\lt 1$ won't be defined.

But $(-(2^{\frac{1}{5}}))^5+1=-1$

Where my analysis went wrong?

Comment: When $n$ is an odd positive integer then $t\to t^{1/n}$ is and "odd" function defined for any real $t$. When $n$ is an even positive integer then $t\to t^{1/n}$ is a function defined for any real $t\geq 0$.

Comment: Why do you say the inverse for $y<1$ won't be defined? It is, in fact, defined.

Comment: @Clayton-So the function would be onto indeed?

Comment: Yes, $x\to x^5+1$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  The same for $x\to x^n+b$ for any positive odd integer $n$ and any real number $b$.